# How to read a utf-8 encoded text file using Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I need to analyse a textfile in tamil (utf-8 encoded). Im using nltk package of Python on the interface IDLE. when i try to read the text file on the interface, this is the error i get. how do i avoid this?

```
corpus = open('C:\\Users\\Customer\\Desktop\\DISSERTATION\\ettuthokai.txt').read()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    corpus = open('C:\\Users\\Customer\\Desktop\\DISSERTATION\\ettuthokai.txt').read()
  File "C:\Users\Customer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 33: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: I haven't fully read your question, but... If you have a load of bytes, you can decode them into a string using `your_bytes.decode("UTF-8")`.

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides - From the traceback, I infer Python3.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are using Python 3, just add the `encoding` parameter to `open()`:

```
corpus = open(
    r"C:\Users\Customer\Desktop\DISSERTATION\ettuthokai.txt", encoding="utf-8"
).read()
```

Comment: Only works in Python 3+. For Python 2, use `codecs.open`.